# Creating a single page application using asp.net MVC4 and AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, single-page-application

> Hi, I am trying to create a single page application using AngularJs
>   and Asp.net MVC4. To start off, I tried to do basic navigation using
>   angular. I followed below steps. 
>   Create MVC4 web application, Selected internet application, 
>   Downloaded AngularJs libraries from Nuget,
>   Referenced it in Bundles.config file Gave reference of Angular in my
>   _layout.cshtml page,
>   Wrote app.js file for routing
>
> Below is the code.
>
> This is my bundles.config file

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                   "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
                  "~/Scripts/app/app.js",
                  "~/Scripts/app/js/controllers.js"));
```

> This is my _Layout.cshtml file. As you can see I have used ng-app
>   directive to let html understand about angular.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
    <body ng-app>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
           <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li><a href="#/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                @*<div ng-view></div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

            @RenderBody()

        </section>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/js/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> This is my Index.cshtml file

```
 @{ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}


    <h1>Angular Tutorial</h1>
    <p>This is an online searchable database for food and nutrition information.</p>

    <h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
```

> I did routing in app.js file which is as follows

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [
'myApp.controllers',
'ngRoute'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Home/Contact', { templateUrl: 'Views/Home/Angular.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1' });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home/About' });
}]);
```

> And last this is my controller. I have written an alert message to
>   check if angular is working.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

 .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {

    alert('Hello from partial One');

});
```

> I don't know what is it that I am doing wrong. I tried several
>   tutorials but could not make it SPA. Please help me. I really want to
>   solve this now. This is getting on my nerves now.  Thanks a lot in
>   advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using Angular and MVC is actually using two MV* frameworks at the same time.

My suggestion is to pick one and use it.  Don't try to use both at the same time as it will just conflict with each other and get you more confused.

Since you're wanting to create a SPA, then your choice should be Angular.  ASP.NET/MVC4 isn't going to give your a SPA, but it can give you a full-featured website.

Plan out what you want first, then pick the technology to get yourself there.  Don't pick the technology first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you that it is confusing me and making SPA with combination of these 2 technologies is difficult. However, I would like to know, how to start with AngularJs in Visual studio. I did see many tutorials but nothing is helping. Can you guide me? Please tell what mistake did I do in the code above Or just tell me the approach to follow.

Comment: Check out John Papa's post on his HotTowel.Angular nuget package.  It'll install all the necessary files and sample pages to get you going.  http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for your reply. I've found a good template for this. This is a link for it. [link] (https://github.com/Vishwa1/AngularTemplate)

Answer (score 1):

You're including angular.js *and* angular.min.js. That could be the issue...nothing else immediately jumps out at me.

Comment: I did that just to resolve the problem. Earlier I had referenced only angular.min.js but it was not working so I referenced angular.js as well as angular.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems:

- your including angular.js and angular.min.js in the same bundle:

  - The bundle minimizes the js files automatically when your not in "optimization" or "debug" mode, so dont reference them at all.
- Your using multiple ng-app tags and I didn't really see a good reason for that:

  - Each application has one ng-app="".
- Your mixing up two different concepts(asp.net razor views + angular js):

  - You need to do this smart and gently. If you want to gain razor's strength for using html helpers\bundles etc. then that's ok only if your sure you know what your doing. How are you going to bind data to your models? I think that you should change you concept and work with asp.net web api instead and use angular "the right way" without mixing stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need anything more than a basic page with some Angular, in Visual Studio, just create an 'ASP.NET Empty Web Application' then add the Angular packages you need, an html file and a JavaScript file and off you go. I did this recently while learning angular and made a simple image carousel with basic navigation. If it helps you out at all, I have GitHub repo with my solution:

`git clone https://github.com/antonosmond/AngularCarousel`

It should give you an idea of how to get started with Angular JS and Visual Studio, without all the complexities of trying to integrate Angular into an MVC app.

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for your reply. I've found a good template for this. This is a link for it. [link] (https://github.com/Vishwa1/AngularTemplate)